# Matplotlib CSV x-ticks overlap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have this dataset of regional temperatures.

It has daily data from many years, (for example 1998-7-12, 2005-4-12) so when I graph it with x as time, the x-lables overlap, and if I rotate them they still overlap.

my code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sheet = pd.read_csv('sheet.csv')

x = sheet['T']
y = sheet['F']
yerror = sheet['E']

plt.title('BHF')
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerror, fmt='o', elinewidth=1)
plt.grid(linestyle=':')

plt.show()
```

It looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1mUZ.png

I'm new to matplotlibs and pandas, so if someone could tell me how to code it so the x ticks only appear, for example every 5 years?

example of how I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp4Oi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to first make sure that the data is in datetime format (check using `sheet.info()` command - column T should say datetime). If not, use `pd.to_datetime()` to change it to date. Once you have plotted the graph, use `set_major_locator()` to set the locators at 5-year ticks and `set_major_formatter()` to set the format you want to display the date time. A simple example is below to showcase the same...

```
sheet = pd.DataFrame({'T': ['1995-1-21', '1998-7-12', '2002-3-15', '2005-4-12'], 'F': [21, 23,43,12],'E': [5, 1,2,3]}) ##Dummy cata

sheet['T'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet['T'], format='%Y-%m-%d') ##Convert column to datetime

x = sheet['T']
y = sheet['F']
yerror = sheet['E']

plt.title('BHF')
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerror, fmt='o', elinewidth=1)
plt.grid(linestyle=':')

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base=5)) ##Ticks should be 5 years apart
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')) ##Format of display of date

plt.show()
```

[image]